# Where do I install puppet for a vm? Host or Guest?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am trying to provision a vagrant box with puppet and I'm terribly confused as to where I need to install puppet. According to Vagrant Documentation under Provisioning, the documentation implies that puppet is on my host machine and when I run `vagrant up` vagrant will look for my manifests and modules on my host environment. [Vagrant Puppet Provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/puppet_apply.html)

However, I don't want to install a bunch of puppet modules and create files on my host. What I want is to start up a vagrant box and then have those manifest files and modules on the virtual machine itself so I can `vagrant package` the box and pass it off to teammates. Vagrant documentation says that I can have the manifest file in the vm like so `puppet.manifests_path = ["vm", "/path/to/manifests"]`, Can I do either or. I'm really confused about how this works.

Additionally, I saw a youtube tutorial that had an accompanying github example [Vagrant example](https://github.com/Ahamedkhan/VagrantPuppetExample1). This guy seems to bypass everything that I read on the puppet documentation. No where in this repository does he specify module classes or packages. Can someone point me to an example of how to provision a box that is best practice?

Comment: You might have better luck on [Super User](//superuser.com)

Comment: Check this is interesting i hope help you
http://superuser.com/questions/743448/is-there-any-reason-to-use-puppet-alongside-with-docker/744101#744101

Comment: I'm not much of a vagrant guy, but you have basically two options with Puppet: (1) put all the needed manifests and data, including modules, on the machine being configured, and use `puppet apply` to apply them, or (2) put the needed manifests and data on a machine running the puppetmaster service, and use `puppet agent` on the machine being configured to retrieve and apply the appropriate configuration.  It sounds like you've seen examples of both.  Puppet itself needs to be on the machine to be configured in any case, however.

Comment: After a quick glance, that link to the example on github is absolutely best practices for using Puppet with Vagrant. Using the vagrant puppet provisioner plugin is definitely the path of least resistance. This WOULD be the answer to your question except simply saying 'yes do it like that link you provided' is kind of a crappy answer in my opinion. Furthermore, if you `vagrant package` then your teammates don't need those modules available or puppet installed. That would be if you passed off the Vagrantfile to them.

Answer (score 0):

> According to Vagrant Documentation under Provisioning, the documentation implies that puppet is on my host machine and when I run vagrant up vagrant will look for my manifests and modules on my host environment.

I am not sure where is the confusion but let me try to clarify.

Puppet like all provisioner runs on the guest (actually the only exception is the [Ansible provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html) and even for Ansible, the vagrant team has since launched the [Ansible local](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html) which runs directly on the guest) so when you have a puppet provisioner :

- vagrant will try to install puppet on the guest VM (if its not already available)
- vagrant will copy the manifest and module files from the host to the guest (generally they will be available on the guest at `/tmp/vagrant-puppet ...`)

so lets look at a given puppet config (a really usual one)

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
end
```

on my host, I do have the following structure

```
.project-directory
|
|---- Vagrantfile
|
|---- puppet
        |-------- hiera.yaml
        |-------- manifests
                     |------- base-app.pp
        |-------- modules
                     |------- ...modules... if any
```

when you do `vagrant up`:

1. vagrant will install puppet if its not available on the guest
2. vagrant will share the `puppet/modules` folder from the host to the guest `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-b14a7087a41f2cfba87af62658880213`
3. vagrant will share the `puppet/manifests` folder from the host to the guest `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3`
4. if provisioner needs to be run (first vagrant up or provisioner flag pass on the CLI) vagrant will execute puppet on the guest the following command :

   ```
   puppet apply --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-b14a7087a41f2cfba87af62658880213:/etc/puppet/modules' --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3 /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-846018e2aa141a5eb79a64b4015fc5f3/site.pp
   ```

so you can see everything is installed on the guest and run on the guest, you only need to maintain on the host the puppet config and modules that will be installed on the guest.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you should directly address what he specifically wants to do: What I want is to start up a vagrant box and then... `vagrant package` the box and pass it off to teammates. That would make this a very good answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard it might be, I took it as the OP wanted to create a box and want to make sure puppet does not need to be installed on host so when distribute his box along with puppet provisioner it will correctly work. DanRubio please clarify and if needed I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Puppet can be installed on the box. Just use this one:

```
config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.2-64-puppet"
```

Comment: this is the os itself, so yes if it has puppet already installed - however if it is a box where puppet is not installed, then what would you do?